# Proper Joist Installation to fix Subfloor Overhang

Tags: bathroom, joists, support, blocking

I am currently doing a full bathroom remodel on a house I just bought.

The entire floor was rotted, so I had to remove it all the way down to the joists. I am planning on sistering two of the joists to add strength lost by the rot, and also am thinking about adding blocking between them for support from twisting.

However, here is my problem:

1. The joists are 2”x10”x12’ and rest on the plates.
2. There will be/is currently a gap from the last joist to the end of the interior wall. This gap is 13” and is the end of the wall where the tub will be going.
3. I would prefer not to have the subfloor (1 & 1/4”) overhang by that amount. My plan is to add 2x10 blocking between the last joist and the exterior wall joist, but I’ve been reading that blocking is more to prevent twisting rather than support.

My question(s):

1. Will the blocking be sufficient to support the tub weight full of water?
2. If not, my next option I’m thinking would be to add a joist in between them (13” over to the edge of the interior wall for the subfloor to sit on - ignore the dryer vent in the picture). The question I have there that I can’t find online: as all the other joists sit on the plate, if I add a joist do I just jack up the floor and attempt to slide the new one into place? Do I nail it or will the future new subfloor hold it in place?

Thank you[image]

Comment: You definitely should not rely on blocking to support much (if any) weight. Adding a new joist to support the edge of the new sub-floor is a *much* better idea.

Comment: The toe plate for that stud wall has to be supported by *something.*  Can't you just sister enough thickness to it for your subfloor to bridge?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Are you referring to sistering to the exterior wall joist a few times? If so, would I need to add the full 12’ joists multiple times, or could I just add a few joists the length of the bathroom and have one side sit on the plate (5’ or so)?